# VERTICA: Which system parameter controls how often containers are condensed?

Tags: vertica

**

> Which system parameter controls how often containers are condensed?

**

Comment: I am guessing MergeOutInterval, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several parameters that control the tuple mover in Vertica, and they can influence each other sometimes.

Here's the documentation on it:
https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AdministratorsGuide/ConfiguringTheDB/TupleMoverParameters.htm